# obtaining preview releases of R Studio Server with wget

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, wget, rstudio

I have set up an R Studio server as an EC2 micro-instance with Amazon Web Services.  I would like to upgrade to the current "preview" release [rstudio-server-0.98.864-amd64.deb](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/download/preview), using something like

`wget <url for preview release>
gdebi rstudio-server-0.98.864-amd64.deb`

However I cannot figure out what the URL is.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

oh, how silly of me.  I shoudl just right-click on the link to the file and copy the link location.